# Open All files named generator.yml in all subdirectories of current directory in gedit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm no expert at shell scripting so I just want a quick answer. I tried something like

```
ls -R|grep generator|gedit
```

but It just doesn't work because it's just a stupid guess. So what's the correct way?

***UPDATE***: answers by Jaypal Singh , kev and Sorin were very helpful but kev's answer covers more cases so I'm marking that correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -name 'generator.yml' -print0 | xargs -0 gedit
```

Or

```
find . -name 'generator.yml' -exec gedit {} +
```

Comment: @JaypalSingh maybe space in subdir.

Answer (score 3):

If you use zsh or a recent bash, it's just:

```
% gedit **/generator.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
find ./ -name generator.yml | xargs gedit
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
find . -name "generator.yml" -exec gedit {} \;
```